# Why is my custom validation not being called?

Tags: django, django-validation, django-forms

I have this model and modelform:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
  text = models.CharField(max_length=100)

  def clean_text(self):
    print "called Comment"
    if len(self.text) <= 5:
      raise ValidationError("must have 5 chars at least")

class CommentForm(ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = Comment

  def clean_text(self):
    print "called CommentForm"
    if len(self.text) <= 5:
      raise ValidationError("must have 5 chars at least")
```

And I'm using them like this in the view:

```
  CommentFormSet = modelformset_factory(model=Comment,form=CommentForm,extra=3)
  if request.method == "POST":
    formset = CommentFormSet(request.POST)
    if formset.is_valid():
      print "VALID FORM"
  else:
    formset = CommentFormSet()
  return render_to_response("first.html",{"formset":formset},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

And this is my template:

```
<form action="first" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {% for dict in formset.errors %}
      {% for error in dict.values %}
          {{ error }}
      {% endfor %}
  {% endfor %}
  <table>
    {{ formset }}
  </table>
  <input type="submit" value="Create"/>
</form>
```

The thing is, my validation is never called. I have 3 comments which I can add at once, and if their text field is empty, django says it's no problem. What am I not doing right?

EDIT: The variant with validator:

```
def validate_min(val):
  print "validator called"
  if len(val) <= 5:
    raise ValidationError("At least 5 characters should be provided")

class Comment(models.Model):
  text = models.CharField(max_length=100,validators=[validate_min])
```

My validator is not being called.

Comment: this is weird. Are you sure you didn't make any duplicated class name?

Comment: I haven't. I noticed that if the text length is different than 0, the validator is called.

Comment: ah then maybe bcoz django model field has blank attribute and default is False. It means the field is required. So the field parent validation works first. It executes custom validation after it passes base field validation

Comment: Ok, but still, why does it show "VALID FORM" ?

Comment: OR maybe custom validation isn't called if the data is blank

Comment: It is useless to check a blank data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I know models don't use clean_% methods. You should use [validator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/validators/).

```
def validate_min_length(value):
    if len(value) <= 5:
        raise ValidationError("must have 5 chars at least")

class Comment(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=100, validators=[validate_min_length])
```

**Edited:** the answer is simple: in formset forms with no data in all fields are ignored. That's why formset is valid. Empty forms [are created](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/forms/formsets.py#L125) with `empty_permitted=True`. Which means they [will pass validation](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/forms/forms.py#L265). Override either of these and you'll get what you want.

Comment: @Geo And `'VALID FORM'` is outputted?

Comment: Yes. Every time I do a post, even though I leave the fields empty.

Comment: But a form with no data is obviously not valid.

Comment: @Geo Imagine a formset with `extra=5`. You will have 5 forms. You fill 2. 2 forms are validated, other 3 are ignored. It's Django's approach. :-) If you want all the five forms to be filled, may be you should check `len(self.forms)` or some other way.

Comment: There should be a way, so that when you call formset.is_valid(), it will return True if all forms passed.

Comment: @Geo Empty forms are [created](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/forms/formsets.py#L125) with `empty_permitted=True`. Which means they [will pass validation](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/forms/forms.py#L265). Override either of these and you'll get what you want.